# Github network graph not displaying correctly merge --no-ff

Tags: git, github

I recently started a new project but it feels like github network is wrong, workflow went like this:

1. From master create new branch develop
2. From develop create new branch menu
3. Some commits on menu branch
4. Merge menu into develop using --no-ff

Network graph looks like this:

[image: Current graph]

By using --no-ff I was expecting something like this:

[image: Expected graph]

Why is my workflow displayed this way? How can I make it like intended?

Edit: I tried using the 'git log --graph --decor' command and graph showed in terminal is correct so I guess it's just the github website representation that's wrong

Comment: As far as I can tell, GitHub's network graph is completely useless. It is not intended to show the graph within a repository (and doesn't); it *is* intended to show the graph across multiple forks and/or users (and doesn't seem to do that either).

Comment: Does your _local_ graph look correct in `gitk` / `git log --graph` / `tig` / SourceTree / whatever tool you like to use?

Comment: @Chris As I said using `git log --graph` my local graph is correct

Answer (score 0):

The [GitHub repository network](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-a-repository-s-network/) is for:

> displaying the branch history of the entire repository network, including branches of the root repository and branches of forks that contain commits unique to the network.

That means, for *one* repo, the branch view is "flattened": you won't see branches on multiple lines: **only one line per repo**, with the occasional "bump" done by one of the repo branches being merged back.